# Direct or indirect passive form?

Tags: passive-voice

> 外国人に質問を聞かれたが、答えられなかった。

Can anybody analyze the grammatical structure of this sentence? Is this an indirect passive sentence? Thanks.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/27800/9831

Answer (score 8):

> **外国人に質問を聞かれた**が、答えられなかった。

I interpret the sentence as "I was asked a question by a foreigner but couldn't answer" (に in 外国人**に** marks 動作主/agent of 聞く), and I don't think it's Indirect Passive Structure (間接受身構文), because...

> Active: 「外国人が私**に**質問**を**聞いた」
>   <sub>(「質問をした」 sounds more natural to me, though)</sub>

has two objects (i.e. direct object 「質問」 and indirect object 「私」), so it can be transformed to two ordinary/direct passive (直接受身) sentences:

> → Direct Passive 1: 「質問が外国人によって私に聞かれた」
>   <sup>(直接目的語「質問」を主語にする場合)</sup>
>   → Direct Passive 2: 「私が**外国人に質問を聞かれた**」
>   <sup>(間接目的語「私」を主語にする場合)</sup>

---

Compare:

> Indirect Passive: 太郎が泥棒に財布を盗まれた
>   × 泥棒が太郎に財布を盗んだ
>   Indirect Passive: 太郎が二階の人に朝までピアノを弾かれた
>   × 二階の人が太郎に朝までピアノを弾いた
>   Indirect Passive: 太郎が妻に死なれた
>   × 妻が太郎に死んだ

Comment: 質問を聞く seems unnatural, but what do you think about 質問を聞かれた? For some reason the original sentence with the passive sounds fine to me.

Comment: 「質問を聞かれた」って、書きはしなくても、会話では言ってるかもしれませんね。通常は「質問された」って言ってそうですけど。

Comment: 「外国人に質問をされた」と言うと、何か尋問されているか、またはもっと正式な場（発表会、会議など）で質問を受けているイメージで、パッと道で知らない人になんか聞かれたら「外国人に質問を聞かれた」の方がしっくりくるって、私だけでしょうか…？（本題からずれた話ばかりですみません）

Comment: パッと道でなんか聞かれたら、「外国人になんか聞かれた」「外国人に道(を)聞かれた」とか言ってるかな～　「質問された」って、なんかもっと難しいこと聞かれたみたいな。。